How can I configure Lombok in IntelliJ for seamless integration?
Lombok not working on intellij ide. Here is the ide version I am currently using:-
IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-233.13135.103, built on December 20, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.9+7-b1087.9 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Registry:
  ide.experimental.ui=true
Non-Bundled Plugins:
  Lombook Plugin (233.13135.65)
Kotlin: 233.13135.103-IJ


Whenever I try to run my code, I get compile time errors like:-
cannot find symbol class Getter
cannot find symbol class Setter
cannot find symbol class NoArgsConstructor
package lombok does not exist
I've tried adding lombok plugin, from the plugin marketplace in intellij
I've download the lombok.jar file, and added to my library (Project Structure -> library)
none of them works

Is it possible provide project example for investigation? Is it possible to check the issue with the latest IDE release?
